# Dividing two numpy arrays resulting in exclusively Nans

Tags: python, numpy, nan, division

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

path = '/Users/me/Desktop/'
filename = '*.tif'

with rasterio.open(path + filename) as src:
    band_red_radiance = src.read(3)

with rasterio.open(path + filename) as src:
    band_nir_radiance = src.read(4)
    
nir = np.array(band_red_radiance)
red = np.array(band_nir_radiance)

nir.dtype #uint16

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
ndvi = np.divide(np.subtract(red, nir), np.add(red, nir))

ndvi.max()
ndvi.min()
```

I can add and subtract both these arrays from each other without issue, but I can't divide them. I'm using numpy's own operators to avoid issues when the data is not a float (it's uint-16), but even when I cast it as a float I still get a min and max of nan.

Comment: What's the output of `print(np.add(red, nir))`? Presumably, there will be some zeros because of wraparound

Comment: Yeah, it adds just fine. Not sure what is meant by wraparound, though.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] to reproduce the issue? You can get a `NaN` by dividing zero by zero: `np.uint16(0) / np.uint16(0)`, so possibly there's some `red[k] == nir[k] == 0`.

Comment: Right, I think I've figured out the issue. I was able to show the value ranges by using `np.nan_to_num(ndvi)`. I guess NaN can show up if your resultant values have too many levels of precision in decimal numbers?

Comment: Also `np.nanmax`